# SQL: Finding values in sets, that only appear once

Tags: sql, oracle

Using Oracle SQL, I need to find the IDs (`ICFPROKEYI`) that occur more then once, but have a certain field (`ICFFLDC`) only once:

```
ICFPROKEYI|ICFKAVKEYI|ICFNUMS|ICFFLDC                      
----------|----------|-------|-----------------------------

   2234884|      5887|      0|Farbe.14870                  
   2234884|      5887|      1|Ueberschrift_i_24291101.18563
   2234884|      5888|      0|Farbe.14870                  
   2234884|      5889|      0|Farbe.14870                  
   2234884|      5890|      0|Farbe.14870                  
   2234884|      5896|      0|Farbe.14870
```

In this case, `2234884`, because it appears 6 times but has a value (`Ueberschrift_i_24291101.18563`) appear only once

Comment: Could you share the query used to arrive at this

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
select a.ICFPROKEYI from table a join table b
on a.ICFPROKEYI = b.ICFPROKEYI and a.ICFFLDC <> b.ICFFLDC
```

Answer (score 1):

`GROUP BY icfprokeyi` and use `HAVING count(*) > 1` to get the `icfprokeyi` that appear more than once and `GROUP BY icfprokeyi, icffldc` and use `HAVING count(*) = 1` to get the `icfprokeyi` where the `icffldc` doesn't exist in another row with the same `icfprokeyi`. Then join both aggregations.

```
SELECT x1.icfprokeyi
       FROM (SELECT t1.icfprokeyi
                    FROM elbat t1
                    GROUP BY t1.icfprokeyi
                    HAVING count(*) > 1) x1
            INNER JOIN (SELECT t2.icfprokeyi
                               FROM elbat t2
                               GROUP BY t2.icfprokeyi,
                                        t2.icffldc
                               HAVING count(*) = 1) x2
                       ON x2.icfprokeyi = x1.icfprokeyi;
```

Comment: this is almost correct! Thanks! But, i also get the items that have only 2 ICFFLDC (one of each). 
I need only items that have one ICFFLDC > 1 and one ICFFLDC not the same COUNT like the others, all within the same ICFPROKEYI.

Something like: ICFPROKEYI where EXISTS (COUNT (t1.ICFFLDC)  > 1  and != COUNT (t2.ICFFLDC))

Answer (score 0):

Here is the postgres query:

```
select ICFPROKEYI,ICFFLDC from table group by ICFPROKEYI,ICFFLDC having count(*)=1;
```

Help yourself to write the oracle equivalent for it.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried this with MySQL and might be applicable in oracle as well.

```
SELECT ICFPROKEYI
FROM <yourtable> WHERE ICFPROKEYI IN
(
    SELECT ICFPROKEYI
    FROM <yourtable>
    GROUP BY ICFPROKEYI
    HAVING COUNT(ICFPROKEYI) > 1
)
GROUP BY ICFPROKEYI, ICFFLDC
HAVING cnt(ICFFLDC) = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `GROUP BY` with `HAVING` (two conditions) as following:

> ```
> SELECT
>     ICFPROKEYI
> FROM <yourtable>
> GROUP BY ICFPROKEYI
> HAVING COUNT(1) > 1
>        AND SUM(CASE WHEN ICFFLDC = 'Ueberschrift_i_24291101.18563' 
>                     THEN 1 END) = 1
> ```

**-- Update**

After @ankit specified that it can be any value(not fixed value - `Ueberschrift_i_24291101.18563`), OP can achieve the desired result using following query:

> ```
> SELECT ICFPROKEYI
> FROM
>     ( SELECT T.ICFPROKEYI,
>             COUNT(1) OVER(
>                 PARTITION BY T.ICFPROKEYI, ICFFLDC
>             ) AS CNT
>         FROM YOURTABLE T
>     )
> WHERE CNT = 1
> ```

Cheers!!

Comment: Comparing with only 1 hardcoded value is not generic enough to handle all conditions.

Comment: I don't think OP asked for any generic solution. Let OP see this and comment. Anyway, thanks for highlighting it. Thanks @AnkitBajpai

Comment: OP have clearly mention - `I need to find the IDs (ICFPROKEYI) that occur more then once, but have a certain field (ICFFLDC) only once` not any particular value.

Comment: No. I'm sorry, this will not do. I need a solution that covers a broader situation

Comment: Check the updated answer. It is the broader solution, that you are looking for

Comment: @Tejash, What if ICFPROKEYI is also Unique in the table. Your second solution will fail.

Comment: ICFPROKEYI is not unique key. See sample data @AnkitBajpai

Comment: What if it is Unique? Sample data doesn't guarantee the authentic data.

Comment: sample data must represent the actual scenario. and OP must have that much sense.

Answer (score 0):

I have replicated this on my local, please find the below SQL block and try it yourself

```sql
drop table test;

CREATE TABLE test(
   ICFPROKEYI INTEGER  NOT NULL 
  ,ICFKAVKEYI INTEGER  NOT NULL
  ,ICFNUMS    number(1,0)  NOT NULL
  ,ICFFLDC    VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO test(ICFPROKEYI,ICFKAVKEYI,ICFNUMS,ICFFLDC) VALUES (2234884,5887,0,'Farbe.14870');
INSERT INTO test(ICFPROKEYI,ICFKAVKEYI,ICFNUMS,ICFFLDC) VALUES (2234884,5887,1,'Ueberschrift_i_24291101.18563');
INSERT INTO test(ICFPROKEYI,ICFKAVKEYI,ICFNUMS,ICFFLDC) VALUES (2234884,5888,0,'Farbe.14870');
INSERT INTO test(ICFPROKEYI,ICFKAVKEYI,ICFNUMS,ICFFLDC) VALUES (2234884,5889,0,'Farbe.14870');
INSERT INTO test(ICFPROKEYI,ICFKAVKEYI,ICFNUMS,ICFFLDC) VALUES (2234884,5888,0,'Farbe.14870');
INSERT INTO test(ICFPROKEYI,ICFKAVKEYI,ICFNUMS,ICFFLDC) VALUES (2234884,5889,0,'Farbe.14870');
INSERT INTO test(ICFPROKEYI,ICFKAVKEYI,ICFNUMS,ICFFLDC) VALUES (2234885,5890,0,'Farbe.14870');
INSERT INTO test(ICFPROKEYI,ICFKAVKEYI,ICFNUMS,ICFFLDC) VALUES (2234885,5896,0,'Farbe.14870');
```

Query

```sql
SELECT A.ICFPROKEYI FROM (select ICFPROKEYI,ICFFLDC, count(*) AS ICFFLDC_CNT from test 
group by ICFPROKEYI,ICFFLDC)A LEFT OUTER JOIN 
(select ICFPROKEYI,count(*) as ICFPROKEYI_CNT from test group by ICFPROKEYI)B 
ON A.ICFPROKEYI = B.ICFPROKEYI WHERE A.ICFFLDC_CNT = 1AND B.ICFPROKEYI_CNT > 1 ;
```